# Default action not resetting on new call

Tags: javascript, jquery, preventdefault

I am having some problems with preventdefault in JavaScript, specifically jQuery. I am trying to get a modal box to show with elements with a class of ".confirm" which effectively overrides the default action confirming with the user if they are sure they want to carry out that action before continuing with what it was set out to do.

```
$('.confirm').on('click', function(event, options)
{
    options = options || {};

    if (!options.confirmed)
    {
        vex.dialog.confirm({
            message: 'Are you sure that you want to perform this action?',
            callback: function(response) {
                if (response === true) {
                    $(event.target).trigger('click', {confirmed: response});
                }
            }
        });

        event.preventDefault();
    }

});
```

### Flow

- Show a modal dialog.
- If the user confirms the action, the click event is fired again, only this time confirmed is passed back to the event handler.
- This would then skip the check and continue with the default action.

### Problem

But this is not the case as it seems that the default action is overriding any future calls from happening regardless.

### Attempts

- Un/Rebinding - requires the user to click it again for it to work.
- window.location (not ideal as it assumes the action is a link but works)
- confirm (doesn't tie in nicely with the aesthetics so needed a better solution)

### Notes

- Needs to be asynchronous.

**Any help would be awesome as it has me stumped for the time being**

Comment: use if(confirm("Are you sure?")){
alert('yes');
}; with no need to preventDefault

Comment: It needs to asynchronous sadly as i am using this modal library which uses callbacks.

Comment: Check out http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/. I think this is what you need to use instead of `preventDefault`

Comment: @TheManiac Thanks but this doesn't prevent the default action.

Comment: Yeah I see that now. Really the only thing it could be is the vex library doing something funky with click events. I set up this fiddle using `console.log` and it all works as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/2kv0o6dm/1/

Comment: I thought that could be the problem as it seems odd for it to be anything else really.

Answer (score 0):

Put event.preventDefault before the API call, this should work I guess.

```
$('.confirm').on('click', function(event, options)
{
    options = options || {};

    if (!options.confirmed)
    {
        event.preventDefault();

        vex.dialog.confirm({
            message: 'Are you sure that you want to perform this action?',
            callback: function(response) {
                if (response === true) {
                    $(event.target).trigger('click', {confirmed: response});
                }
            }
        });


    }

});
```

EDIT:

I think this is the only way without unbind/rebind as you said.

```
$('.confirm').on('click', function(event, options)
{
    options = options || {};

    if (!options.confirmed)
    {
        event.preventDefault();

        vex.dialog.confirm({
            message: 'Are you sure that you want to perform this action?',
            callback: function(response) {
                if (response === true) {
                    $(event.target).trigger('click', {confirmed: response});
                }
            }
        });


    }
    else {
        window.location = $(this).attr("href");
    }

});
```

Comment: Nope, this doesn't seem to work either, not that moving it about should really make much of a difference as the dialog is asynchronous so it should pass right though.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question first time. What element is .confirm ? <a> <input type="submit"/> <button type="submit">. Are you sure the second click event is firing?

Comment: The second event is firing correctly but because of the initial attempt being blocked, seems to stop the intended action (in this case a link) from firing.

Comment: Oh, I know the problem... Your best option is something like `if (!options.confirmed){ //code } else {window.location = $(this).attr("href");}`

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the click handler with `$('.confirm').off()` in your callback. This way, when you programmatically trigger the click, your click handler be called.

Comment: Works but requires clicking the button again like previous solutions (re/unbinding). Thanks though we are inching closer :)